# What is the best way to set up last-modified and date-record-added fields?

Tags: mysql

Hi I would like to set and forget two fields for tracking the date the record was added and also the date the record was last modified in a mySQL database.

I am using "ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP" and was hoping I would just change UPDATE to INSERT.

No luck however. Can anyone give me the heads up on the best way to achieve this? - preferably inside the database itself.

Answer (score 14):

This assumes MySQL 5.  Simply add two triggers:

```
create table foo (a1 INT, created timestamp, updated timestamp) engine=innodb;

DELIMITER |

CREATE TRIGGER foo_created BEFORE INSERT ON foo
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
SET new.created := now();
SET new.updated := now();
END;

|

CREATE TRIGGER foo_updated BEFORE UPDATE ON foo
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
SET new.updated := now();
END;
|

DELIMITER     ;

insert into foo (a1) values(7);
select * from foo;

update foo set a1=9;
```

Answer (score 4):

You basically need both columns to be setup as timestamps with default values of `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`.  Unfortunately, this is not allowed in MySQL:

```
Error Code: 1293
Incorrect table definition; there can be only one TIMESTAMP column with CURRENT_TIMESTAMP in DEFAULT or ON UPDATE clause
```

You can't have two timestamp columns, even though you need one to only have a default value of `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`, and the other one to be `UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`, this is still not allowed.

Your best bet here would be to specify as so:

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
`addedDate` dateTime,
`lastModified` timestamp on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
)
```

Unfortunately, you'll have to set the 'addedDate' manually on insert using the `NOW()` function.

Comment: Thanks - that's what I thought. It would be nice to not have to. Anyhow thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 0):

mySQL has a NOW() function you can use, see the tutorial at [Tutorials Point](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-insert-query.htm) that can help you put it in place.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a DATETIME column and set it when you create the row of data. That will serve as the date the record was added.

Next, add a [TIMESTAMP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/timestamp-pre-4-1.html) column:

> Automatic updating of the first TIMESTAMP column in a table occurs under any of the following conditions:
>
> - You explicitly set the column to NULL.
> - The column is not specified explicitly in an INSERT or LOAD DATA INFILE statement.
> - The column is not specified explicitly in an UPDATE statement and some other column changes value. An UPDATE that sets a column to the value it does not cause the TIMESTAMP column to be updated; if you set a column to its current value, MySQL ignores the update for efficiency.

The TIMESTAMP column will take care of your record modified date.